# How to reisze the UITableViewCell according to UIView(hide or display) in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button and a UIView in UITableViewCell ,The UIView is controlled by button, When I click the button The UIView will display or hide(toogle) and the UITableView will resize according to UIView(display or hide) 
The Question is : How to resize the UITableViewCell after I click the button

I have try to use `tableview.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)` in `tableView(tableView:UITableView,heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)` to get UIView status but get error

Answer (score 0):

I use an Array to controll the height of UITableViewCell